# Lift Record: empty value for required field but no validation errors

Tags: validation, scala, lift, lift-record

I've been trying to figure out how to do this without manually defining a validation but without any success so far.

I have a `StringField`

```scala
class Foo private() extends MongoRecord[Foo] with ObjectIdKey[Foo] {
  ...
  object externalId extends StringField(this, 255) {
    // none of these seem to have any effect on validation whatsoever:
    override def optional_? = false
    override def required_? = true
    override def defaultValueBox = Empty
  }
  ...
}
```

Now when I call `.validate` on a `Foo`, it returns no errors:

```scala
val foo = Foo.createRecord
foo.validate match {
  case Nil => foo.save
  ...
}
```

...and the document is saved into the (mongo) DB with no `externalId`.

So the question is: is there *any* way at all to have Lift automatically validate missing fields without me having to manually add stuff to `validations`?

**EDIT:** am I thinking too much in terms of the type of productivity that frameworks like Django and Rails provide out of the box? i.e. things like basic and very frequent validation without having to write anything but a few declarative attributes/flags. If yes, why has Lift opted to not provide this sort of stuff out of the box? Why would anybody *not* want `.validate` to automatically take into consideration all the `def required_? = true`/`def optional_? = false` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a way for you to validate a field without explicitly defining validations.  The reason that `optional_?` and `required_?` don't provide validation is that it isn't always clear what logic to use, especially for non `String` fields.  The `required_?` value itself is used by Crudify to determine whether to mark the field as required in the produced UI, but it's up to you to provide the proper logic to determine that the requirement is satisfied.

Validating the field can be as easy as

```
override def validations = super.validations :: valMinLen(1, "Required!")
```

Or see the answer to your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410904/generic-field-validation-with-traits-in-lift) for how to create a generic `Required` trait.

Comment: My assumption was that, given such a highly productive and relatively mature framework, such requirement would have popped up a million times before, and that there's something that just works out of the box... but anyway, what's the purpose of `required_?` and `optional_?` anyway then?

Comment: By the way, it's not entirely obvious how one would go about defining such a `Required` trait, given the types involved...

Comment: That example doesn't compile, even after fixing `def validations` to `valMinLen(1, "Required") _ :: super.validations`; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410904/generic-field-validation-with-traits-in-lift

Comment: OK, thanks! Are `optional_?` and `required_?` *only* used by Crudify, by the way?

Comment: Actually there is at least one other difference: the default/initial `valueBox` for an `StringField { optional_? = false }` will contain `Full("")` whereas `optional_? = true` will result in `Empty`; `required_? = true|false` does not have the same effect though. (same with other field types)