# Generic field validation with traits in Lift

Tags: validation, scala, lift, traits, lift-record

I'm trying to define a `trait Required` to encapsulate the logic to validate the presence of required `Record` `Field`s, however, I haven't been able to figure out what the self type should be. My goal is to be able to write something as close as possible to e.g. `object foo extends SomeField(...) with Required`, however I do realize I might have to explicitly pass in some type parameters to `Required`.

My incompetent take so far has been:

import net.liftweb.record.Field
import net.liftweb.util.FieldError

```
trait Required[ThisType, OwnerType] {
  this: Field[ThisType, OwnerType] =>
  def errMsg = "is required"

  override def validations = {
    val required =
      (x: String) => if (x.isEmpty) List(FieldError(this, errMsg)) else Nil
    // this asInstanceOf call also seems fishy
    // --why's it even required if we already have the self type in place?
    required :: super.asInstanceOf[Field[ThisType, OwnerType]].validations
  }
}
```

however, this leads to compilation errors and warnings related to existential types from:

```
myfield = object SomeField(...) with Required[SomeField[SomeModel], SomeModel]
```

not to mention it's as far as it gets from the concise `with Required`.

**EDIT:**

I've come up with this instead:

```
trait Required[OwnerType] extends Field[String, OwnerType] {
  def errMsg = "is required"

  override def validations = {
    val required =
      (x: String) => if (x.isEmpty) List(FieldError(this, errMsg)) else Nil
    required :: super.validations
  }
}
```

however, it doesn't allow me to prepend `required` to `super.validations` because it expects `this.type.ValueType => List[FieldError]` not `String => List[FieldError]`, which I find odd because in the case of `Field[String, ...]`, `ValueType` *is* `String`.

If I change `required` to be `ValueType => ...`, it compiles, but `with Required[SomeModel]` errors out with:

> type arguments [String,OwnerType] do not conform to trait Field's type parameter bounds [ThisType,OwnerType <: net.liftweb.record.Record[OwnerType]]

...even though `StringField.ThisType` is `String` and `String.OwnerType` is a subclass of `Record[SomeModel]`, `SomeModel` being a subclass of `MongoRecord[SomeModel]`. —I'm lost.

P.S. This is related to [Lift Record: empty value for required field but no validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395669/lift-record-empty-value-for-required-field-but-no-validation-errors/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following compiles in the SBT console.

```
import net.liftweb.util._
import net.liftweb.record._
import net.liftweb.record.field._

trait Required extends StringTypedField {

  override def validations: List[ValidationFunction] = valMinLen(1, "Required!") _ :: super.validations

}

class TestRecord extends Record[TestRecord] {

    val meta = TestRecord

    object testField extends StringField(this, 255) with Required

}

object TestRecord extends TestRecord with MetaRecord[TestRecord]
```

Comment: This is very nice indeed! Could you perhaps explain how one would realize that this was the right solution? Does this require deeper insight into how Lift Record has been built/designed? Or is it just my lack of experience with Lift/Scala that caused me to fail to see that I need to use `StringTypedField` as the self-type? (I actually did come up with a working mixin but it was far more complicated)

Comment: A little bit of both.  Working the typing out is definitely a Scala thing, but knowing that it's easier to just use StringTypedField comes with Lift familiarity.

Comment: Looks like this leads to infinite recursion; in order to fix this, I replaced the self type with `extends StringTypedField` and called `super.valiations` instead. (feel free to incorporate my edits into the answer and remove my note).

Comment: Updated.  I wanted to avoid the explicit inheritence, but I guess there is no way to refer to the validations method of the self type.  If you reference super without extending the trait, it won't compile.  I suppose this will work at least.

Comment: This definitely works... however, meanwhile, I've realized that in the end, it's easier to gather most of the validation logic for fields of any type to a single function that simply iterates over `rec.fields`, checks the `required_?` attribute and acts accordingly, with special cases defined with `match { case ... }`... otherwise it's just too much hassling with the type system for too little benefit (e.g. http://pastebin.com/P2pNg05b)